# Ramda: if func returns truthy value, use it in compose, else return as is

Tags: ramda.js

is there any neat Ramda way of writing something like this:

```
 const ifOkCompose = (...args) => {
            const r = foo(...args);

            if (r) {
                return compose(bar1, bar2)(r);
            }

            return r;
        };
```

If foo() returns truthy value, send it to compose, otherwise just return it. There is 'when', but it would return arguments instead of returned value of 'foo(...)'.

In other words, I have a function foo which may return undefined, I use it in compose as `compose(bar1, bar2, foo)`. If foo(...) returns undefined I want to kick out of compose and just return undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs example for [`R.composeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeWith) is close to what you want.

```js
const composeWhileNotNil = R.composeWith((f, res) => R.isNil(res) ? res : f(res))

composeWhileNotNil([bar1, bar2, foo])
```

The biggest difference is that this will stop the composition on *any* nil response, not just the first.  Obviously you can alter it easily if you want to stop only `undefined` and not `null`.

Comment: Much better indeed. I keep seeing the same pattern applied to `composeWith` or `pipeWith`, that is "if not false apply res to f otherwise return res". Is there a space for `composeUnless` (and `pipeUnless`) that would keep applying the return value to the function until the predicate returns false?

Comment: Thanks, thats even better. Yeah its actually in docs, close to what i was looking for :)

Comment: It just has to be used as `composeWhileNotNil([bar1, bar2, foo])`

Comment: @givehug: Correct.  Updated.  That's what I get for not testing.

Comment: @customcommander: probably not.  `[compose|pipe]With` were added to reduce the number of `compose`/`pipe` functions supplied.  Thus `composeWithNotNil` is like the above.  `composeP` becomes `composeWith(then)`, `composeK` becomes `composeWith(chain)`.  The function supplied is not a predicate but rather one that accepts the current value and a transforming function and returns a new value that can be passed through.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work:

```
const ifOkCompose = pipe(foo, when(identity, compose(bar1, bar2)));
```

1. The initial arguments are passed to `foo`
2. The result is then passed to `identity` that performs a truthy check
3. When truthy, result is passed to `compose(bar1, bar2)`
4. Otherwise result is returned as is

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make something like that :)